# I am trying to start mysql-client in Docker but i get access denied for user error

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to connect MySQL Client to docker. I can connect just fine on the MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client, but when I try to connect to it from docker I get this error:

C:\Users\Bolin>docker exec -it mysql mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am on a window machine and I am trying to follow this tutorial
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mysql-docker-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, looks like the issue is with privilege user for the database table,
Try to create a privileged user in your database named root. After that please check again

==========================================================================================
try these queries in your databse:

```
INSERT INTO mysql.user (Host, User, Password) VALUES ('%', 'root', password('YOURPASSWORD'));
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

if the above code doesn't work try with the second

```
$mysql -u root mysql
$mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('my_password') where USER='root';
$mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```