# Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES) in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created `mysql` docker container using docker-compose file, container is up and running fine now. `docker-compose.yaml` is:

```yaml
version: '3'
  services:
     db:
        image: "mysql:8.0.21"
        container_name: test-mysql
        #- mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql/data
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        environment:
           MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Test123
            MYSQL_DB=imonitor
        volumes:
             -  vol-data:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
             -  my-app
      backend-app:
        build: ./back-end
        container_name: back-end-container
        environment:
          - DB_SERVER= test-mysql
          - MYSQL_DB=testdb
          - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
        ports:
         - 3000:3000
        networks:
          -  my-app
        links:
          -   my-app
      ui:
        build: ./front-end
        container_name: front-end-container
        ports:
          - 8090:80
        links:
          - backend-app
        networks:
          - my-app
networks:
  my-app:
    driver: bridge
  volumes:
    vol-data:
```

Using interactive terminal command I have tried to get into MySQL database:

`docker exec -it 90585b0a534a bash root@90585b0a534a:/# mysql -u root -pTest123 mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Also, unable to connect using dB visualizer. is there any fault in the YAML file or on the configuration file?

Comment: have you tried "mysql" without any user/pwd? or only the host? that usually works, unless you expressly set up authentication, in which case I'd look into that...

Comment: Yes nick i did tried, without user and password

Comment: Do you see any errors in the mysql container logs?

Comment: @Carlos, seems not such error, here is logs of db

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am trying to start mysql-client in Docker but i get access denied for user error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653320/i-am-trying-to-start-mysql-client-in-docker-but-i-get-access-denied-for-user-err)

Comment: masseyb let me go through this link will update

Comment: INSERT INTO mysql.user (Host, User, Password) VALUES ('%', 'root', password('YOURPASSWORD'));
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
where to put these line of code?

Comment: Found issue in yaml indentation, changed it